# Arquillian test Coverage

Tags: java, integration-testing, code-coverage, jboss-arquillian, jacoco

I would like to see the **test coverage for IT tests** run with Arquillian. I ran into this extension: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco

What I dont understand is why **CoverageBean** class tested by **JacocoInegrationTestCase** is not visible in the reports. Thats what I would expect.
Can somebody provide the example project, with 1 integration test running on Arquillian and tested class for which the test coverage report is generated, please?
Thanks

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class JacocoInegrationTestCase
{
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() throws Exception
{
   return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                 .addClasses(CoverageBean.class, JacocoInegrationTestCase.class);
}
@EJB
private CoverageBean bean;
@Test
public void shouldBeAbleToGenerateSomeTestCoverage() throws Exception
{
  Assert.assertNotNull(bean);    
  bean.test(true);
```

}
}

```
@Stateless
public class CoverageBean
{
public void test(Boolean value) 
{
  String test = "test";
  if(value)
  {
     if(test.length() == 4)
     {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        test = String.valueOf(start);
     }
  } 
  else
  {
     long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     test = String.valueOf(start);
  }
```

}
}

```
 <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
   </configuration>
<executions>
   <execution>
     <id>integration-tests</id>
     <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>test</goal>
   </goals>
<configuration>
   <environmentVariables>
      <JBOSS_HOME>${jbossHome}</JBOSS_HOME>
   </environmentVariables>
<skip>false</skip>
<includes>
    <include>org/jboss/arquillian/extension/jacoco/test/unit/ * </include>
         <include>org/jboss/arquillian/extension/jacoco/test/integration/ * </include>   
</includes>
</configuration>
</execution>
```

**EDIT:**
I have also try this project (https://github.com/CSchulz/arquillian-jacoco-showcase), looks very promissing but it runs against the distribution verison of Wildfly.. But in my project we are running Arquillian tests agains the installed instance of JBOSS EAP 6, with database connection and other security configuration. Is anybody able to change it in order to use the installed (deployed) version of JBOSS? Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your config and the deployment?

Comment: Project can be donwloaded from the github. I updated my answer with few relevant code snippets. Stil wondering why the coverage its not calculated, eventhought the code is called.

Comment: An the Arquillian side, all you'd need to do is change the arquillian dependency to what you're already using in your project, and also change the Java EE version. You said your project is available in github, but you didn't add a link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the configuration that works for me.  See if it helps you.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.plugin.maven.surefire}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                <excludedGroups>org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.plugin.maven.failsafe}</version>
            <configuration>
                <groups>org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian</groups>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <arquillian.launch>jbossas-remote-7</arquillian.launch>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>.....</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Create Unit Test Report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Create Integration Test Report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I am facing same problem and tried your answer, getting different error. could you please help me on this .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412555/arquillian-tomee-7-1-0-integration-test-code-coverage-issue-with-jacoco

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you've provided, it looks like you haven't executed the `prepare-agent` goal. You can see the full example in the [README](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco/blob/master/README.asciidoc).

Comment: Hi @LightGuard, thanks for the answer. The problem is, that Iam using arquillian tests running on JBOSS EAP 6  using database and other security configurations.  So to run in against the distributed version of wildfly or JBOSS would not solve my problem. If you know about some dummy example project, that run Aquillian tests against the class using DAO, it would be very helpful. Thanks